# what is the best way to gather data from employees inside the company?

Tags: .net, forms, automation, macros

we have about 200 employees

i need to help HR to automate stuff

one of the things that they need is to gather information from employees before they interview and after they become an official employee

GOOGLE FORMS is one way to do it

but can anyone recommend a very simple out of the box way to push forms to different employees inside the company and externally?

has anyone done this with out looks?

we want to get away from physical paper forms to electrnoic

Comment: is this a programming question or a fundamental "data collecting" question.  If it's programming related, then... you need you have some sort of UI and storage mechanism where you can iterate through the data and gather results.  If you're using .NET, then you need to decide if it's web based, desktop based. What type of data store you want... etc etc etc...

Comment: do you seriously think a macro is in any way appropriate for you to collect employee data?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question.  (And the answer "Email?" seems to obvious...)

Comment: ah, but email isn't automated ;)

Comment: Surprised not to see Outlook Forms suggested ... if you already have Exchange, check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://wufoo.com is another one of those form building services you could consider. Though depending on the data you are collecting you might want to really consider if a public form hosted by someone else is acceptable for the data.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.jotform.com/pricing

Jotform is one of the similar services i like. Using a web-based solution is cost-effective and you can use them right away you start a membership.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged .NET and Forms. Why not make a simple "one page" web form with all the required fields. Have it punch the information into a database (SQLCE, SQL Server, MS Access< Etc).

Host it on a local server running IIS. pass the URL out to the employees, and have them punch in their own data.

From there you can simply hand the raw data over to HR in a spreadsheet, or if you're feeling ambitious, write a small reporting app for data mining.